# How to get the position of the row with some key from a Deedle Frame<DateTime,_>?

Tags: f#, deedle

By position I mean:

```
let position:int = positionForKey frame key
let row =
  Frame.take positionForKey
  |> frame.takeLast 1
```

Then, `row` should be a Frame with only one row, whose key is `key`.

What I don't know is how to achieve `positionForKey`. One idea that should work but I don't know if it's the best way of doing it would be to create another `Series` via `Series.scanValues` and let the values be the positions, but I think there oughts to be a more elegant way of doing it.

The implementation via `Series.scanValues` would be:

```
let positionForKey (frame:Frame<'K,_>) (key:'K) =
  let positions = Series.scanValues (fun pos _ -> pos + 1) 0 (frame.GetColumnAt 0)
  positions.[key]
```

... index beginning from `1`

**Example**

Say you have a Frame `f` like this:

```
03/01/01,  4 , ...
04/01/01,  3 , ...
05/01/01,  6 , ...
   ...  , ..., ...
```

then, `positionforKey f 04/01/01 = 2`, `positionforKey f 05/01/01 = 3` and so on. (Supposing that 04/01/01 was a valid DateTime)

Comment: @FoggyFinder Sure, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deedle actually has built-in function for doing this, but they are not very well documented (mostly because this has been changing quite a bit when we were adding support for "virtual frames").

However, consider a sample data frame:

```
let ts = series [ for i in 0 .. 365 -> DateTime(2017, 1, 1).AddDays(float i) => float i]
let df = frame ["Sample" => ts ]
```

The data frame has a row index which represents how the lookup using indices is performed. Using the `RowIndex`, you can locate the key and then translate the returned address to an index:

```
let addr = df.RowIndex.Locate(DateTime(2017, 5, 1))
let idx = df.RowIndex.AddressOperations.OffsetOf(addr)
```

And then you can get a frame with just this row:

```
df.GetRowsAt([| int idx |])
```

The address `addr` is just the index when you are working with in-memory data frames, but [in virtual data frames](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle.BigDemo) it would be a number that encodes where the row is stored and so it would not directly map to an offset. That's why I added the `OffsetOf` call, which maps the address to an actual index. Though in case of in-memory frames, you do not need to worry about this.

If the key is not found, the `addr` value will be `-1L` (though in principle, you should use `Addressing.Address.invalid` when checking for this).

Comment: ah, this is very nice, I saw the `Address` in the code and was wondering what it is and how `.RowIndex` could be used!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the position of the key in several ways, for example using `.RowIndex`. But the simplest way is probably just get the keys and find the index. You might want to use `TryFindIndex`, where df is a dataframe, indexed by DateTime.

`df.RowKeys |> Seq.findIndex(fun x -> x = DateTime(2017,5,6))`

If you just want to return a row at the specified index, there is an extension method for that. Here are some ways to get at the row by index:

`(Frame.getRow (DateTime(2017,5,6)) df):Series<string,string>`

or

`df.Rows.[(DateTime(2017,5,6))]`

If you want to do something fancier you should certainly consult the [Deedle](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/tutorial.html), and [Frame docs](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/frame.html).

Comment: the findIndex method is more efficient, I'll change my definition for positionForKey, yet I still believe that there ought to be a better way. I skimmed through the docs and I didn't find something better, maybe I missed it. Thanks!